# Interchange data between TabActivity and its sub-Activities. Possible?

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have a list of locations saved in the TabActivity. The TabActivity has 2 sub-activities: a map and a list. So i want to get the location-list to the sub-activities to show them there. I know that i can commit some data with the intent, but i always want to commit the data to the current showing sub-activity if the list changes.
Is there a possiblity to do this?

For further details, please ask me.

Thanks a lot,
joe

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot determine current active tab? or you can't exchange data at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, You can have access to the sub activities of `TabActivity`.
You can get the current active `Activity` like this way:

say you have a `Button`(typically other than `TabIndicators`) somewhere in `TabActivity` which call `doSomeAction()` in its `onClick()` to refresh or change your Sub-Activity contents. You will do it this way:

```
//this method is in TabActivity
public void doSomeAction(View button)
{
    Activity currentAct = this.getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
    int index = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
    if(index == 0)
    {
        MyListAct listAct = (MyListAct)currentAct; //MyListAct or any other Sub Activity
        listAct.refreshList(); // refreshList() may be a method to refresh Activity    
    }
    //else you can check for the other Activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a static global data container and commit your changes into that object (you could clear and setup it with the aid of the main activity life cycle). But make sure you don't leak any heavy resources, especially a context reference.

Comment: Is there then a possibility that the list of the sub activity recognise the change of the static data?

Comment: The same question I was asking myself while I wrote that answer. I would try to implement some kind of a `changed`-flag mechanism. Maybe a simple timestamp of last change so your activity knows which was the last change it *consumed*.